# Why Google browser to upload pictures use WebUploader reaction is very slow

Tags: javascript, uploader

Google is very slow,but I use other browsers, such as Firefox, IE and so on, are not the problem. Even after I broke the net, the picture was still very quick.
WebUploader version is  0.1.5,Google's version is 54.0.2840.71 m.

Comment: chrome F12 ,NetWork,check the http status.

Answer (score -1):

I get it.i think you can resolve it by following methods: 
1.you can set timeout option;
example: 
this is default time: timeout: 2 * 60 * 1000, 
of course,you can set any number for this option;as for me,i set it as 1 * 60 * 1000.

i hope can help you